# "The Events Calendar" plugin by Modern Tribe in Wordpress not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, calendar

I'm using the "The Events Calendar" plugin by Modern Tribe. I have the following code at the beginning of a php file that is loaded with an ajax get statement.

```
if (!function_exists('tribe_create_event')) { 
    echo "function does not exist";
        return;
}
```

Here's the ajax call.

```
jQuery.get("http://allthingsbahai.net/wp-content/themes/accelerate-child/insertdate.php",
                    {gregdate: gregdate, badidate: badidate},
                    function(result, status) {
                        alert(status);
                        alert(result);
                        //alert(result.badidate);
                        //alert(result.gregdate);
                    }            
            );
```

It returns with a status of success, and "function does not exist" for the result. I'm baffled at this point. The calendar works fine, accepts entries through the wordpress admin interface, and displays properly.
I'm stumped.

Comment: does tribe_create_event function exists?

Comment: It's part of "The Event Calendar" interface. 
[link to documentation](https://theeventscalendar.com/plugin/the-events-calendar/page/2/)
[link to more documentation](https://theeventscalendar.com/function/tribe_create_event/)
The plugin is installed and activated, so I don't have any idea why it's not working.

Comment: why aren't you using the prefered way of calling ajax in wordpress via wp_ajax action?

Comment: Why aren't you trying to contact them on the [support](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/the-events-calendar)?

Answer (score 0):

You're calling to a file `http://allthingsbahai.net/wp-content/themes/accelerate-child/insertdate.php` directly. This file may not load up other files. And direct call to a file is aborted by WP and other Plugins by the following code.

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}
```

You've to follow the WP way of AJAX by using actions, head over to Codex for more details.
https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: Solved it by a function and add_action( 'wp_ajax_insert_dates', 'insert_dates'); and 
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_insert_dates', 'insert_dates' );
How does one make the "code" tag work in the comments?